# What does "(?! ... )" do in a Perl regex?

Tags: regex, perl

```
 $str = "doctor_who:eeh1234LMNOP51234.123";
```

I want to match `doctor_who:ee` not `doctor_who:eeh`;

```
 $str =~ m/doctor_who:e(?!eh)[epx];
```

I want to know the role of regular expression within Parentheses;

Comment: Please learn to format your posts properly. You should read [*Markdown Editing Help*](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Comment: `$str =~ m/doctor_who:e(?!eh)[epx];` won't compile. Please *copy and paste* your **real code** into any questions

Comment: `(?!PAT)` means "is not followed by `PAT`", or more precisely, "`PAT` does not match at this position".

Answer (score 3):

A component like `(?! ... )` will fail to match if the following characters in the target string match the enclosed regex pattern. It's called a *negative look-ahead*

It's unclear whether you need help to form a pattern to your requirements, or if you've come across a pattern that you don't understand

If I was writing it, I'd look at your specification

> *I want to match 'doctor_who:ee' not 'doctor_who:eeh'*

You want to match `doctor_who:ee` that isn't followed by `h`, which is

```
/doctor_who:ee(?!h)/
```